# Python naming conventions for attributes and methods meant to be overwritten

Tags: python, naming-conventions, template-method-pattern

I have some object oriented code in Python, where some classes are meant to be extended to provide the missing custom bits of code (a la [Template Method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), but also with variables), that will only be used by the super class, not by the client code using them.

Are there any style conventions for such *abstract* (or dull, because their implementation in the super class would be either `pass` or raise a `NonImplemented` exception) methods and attributes?

I've been browsing the [PEP-0008](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and it only mentions about prepending an underscore to *private* members not intended to be used by subclasses.

Comment: The convention is to document it in the docstrings for the class, as far as I know... I don't think there's a specific convention other than that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all i think that you are mistaken when you say that:

> about prepending underscore to private members not intended to be used by subclasses.

Actually prepending a method/attribute by underscore is a python convention that mean that this method/attribute shouldn't be accessed outside the class (and its subclass) and I think you forgot to read about the double underscore that is used to make a method/attribute not possible to override.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __foo(self):
        print "foo"
    def main(self):
        self.__foo()


class Bar(Foo):
    def __foo(self):
        print "bar"


bar = Bar()
bar.main()
# This will print "foo" and not "bar".
```

---

There is another way of declaring stub method by the way which is using [abc.ABCMeta](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta) and [abc.abstractmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod).

Answer (score 13):

I usually use single underscore e.g. `_myvar` for protected (as in C++) methods/attributes, which can be used by derived classes and use double underscore e.g. `__var` when it should not be used by anybody else, and as double-underscore names at class definition level are [mangled](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers), so they can't be overridden in derived class e.g.

```
class A(object):
    def result1(self): # public method
        return self._calc1()

    def result2(self): # public method
        return self.__calc2()

    def _calc1(self): # protected method, can be overridden in derived class
        return 'a1'

    def __calc2(self): # private can't be overridden
        return 'a2'


class B(A):
    def _calc1(self):
        return 'b1'

    def __calc2(self):
        return 'b2'

a = A()
print a.result1(),a.result2()
b = B()
print b.result1(),b.result2()
```

Here it seems derived class `B` is overriding both `_calc1` and `__calc2` but `__calc2` isn't overridden because its name is already mangled with class name and hence output is

```
a1 a2
b1 a2
```

instead of

```
a1 a2
b1 b2
```

but ultimately choose any convention and document it, also in above case it is not that base class can't override private, here is a way :)

```
class B(A):
    def _calc1(self):
        return 'b1'

    def _A__calc2(self):
        return 'b2'
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a naming convention for these methods because they'll have the same name when they're overridden.  Otherwise they wouldn't be overridden!  I think having the method to be overridden do something trivial, and documenting it accordingly, is good enough:

```
class MyClass:

  def aMethod():
    '''Will be overridden in MyDerivedClass'''
    pass
```

Name mangling, which you mention in your question, is useful if you have a non-trivial method that will be overridden, but you still want to be able to access the base version.  See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) for more info and an example.